# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable at solr.DefaultSource.createRelation

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen many such posts for serialization error. But I am new to this.

There is a dataframe-modProductsData and a map L2L3Map Map. I want to replace the values in column-PRIMARY_CATEGORY with values of map-L2L3Map.

```
val L2L3Map = L2.collect.map(row => (row.get(0).toString, row.get(1).toString)).toMap
val L2L3MapUDF = udf { s: String => L2L3Map.get(s) }
val productsData = spark.read.format("solr").options(readFromSourceClusterOpts).load
var modProductsData = productsData.withColumn("Prime_L2_s", when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isNotNull, when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isin(L3ids:_*), L2L3MapUDF(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY"))).otherwise(when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isin(L2ids:_*),col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY")).otherwise(lit(null)))).otherwise(lit(null)))
```

Below are the more error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at solr.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:31) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215) 
... 89 elided 
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable 
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288) 
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108) 
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2101) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:841)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362) 
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:840) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371) 
at
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It worked with below code :)

def mapPhantom(flagMap: Map[String, String]): (String) => String = {
    (id: String) =>
      {
        flagMap.getOrElse(id,null)  
      }
  }

val L2L3Map = L2.collect.map(row => (row.get(0).toString, row.get(1).toString)).toMap
val L2L3UDF = udf(mapPhantom(L2L3Map))

var modProductsData = productsData.withColumn("Prime_L2_s", when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isNotNull, when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isin(L3ids:_*), L2L3UDF(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY"))).otherwise(when(col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY").isin(L2ids:_*),col("PRIMARY_CATEGORY")).otherwise(lit(null)))).otherwise(lit(null)))
```